# How to check if the scroll button for a grid or table has reached till the bottom of the table/grid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a application where I have to read all values from all rows of a grid. The values load upon scrolling through the scroll bar that the grid has.
I am using the below code to scroll-

```
  WebElement scroll =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of scroll bar"));
  scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

I want to know whether there is a way to know that the scroll bar has scrolled to the end of the table/grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current max row number of the table or number of rows and click on page down. Again, take the no of rows and compare it with previous count. if it is matching then the scroll bar reached at max.

Answer (score 0):

The general principle is to check the value of window.pageYOffset in the browser. If your button scrolls completely at the bottom then window.pageYOffset should have some positive value (If you get '0' it means it has not ). Assuming the driver variable holds your WebDriver instance:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return window.pageYOffset;");
```

`executeScript` is used to run JavaScript code in the browser.

**OR**
You don't need to scroll down your window just use Arraylist and get all the elements of the parent xpath of particular column or grid :

1) Declare ArrayList:

```
 List<WebElement> var = new ArrayList<>();
```

2) Intialize var:

```
var=driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of parent class or div which contains that data"));
```

3) Use for loop for printing or do whatever you need to do inside this loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(var.get(i).getText());
    }
```

If you get the last value / record of the table or grid it means window has scrolled down completely . I tried my best to help you . Let me know whether it works for you or not .

Comment: Its a dynamic table/Grid so I have no fixed data to cross check for.